# PHP get integer from string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, integer

I have a massive database storing customers' orders.
I have to create a report (monthly and yearly) by total products sales and products brands sales.

The main trouble is that in every order entry, I got a column called items, which stores ordered products info like:

> [32] (1 x 22 EUR) prod name wxy
> Code:XY
> Color:LRC Red Cherry
>   [42] (1 x 33 EUR) prod name fgh
> Code:XY
> Color:pink [66] (1 x
>   44 EUR) prod name abc
> Code:YU
> Color:LPK Pink [60] (6 x 45 EUR)
>   prd name xyz
> Code:XY [1965] (1 x 32 EUR) prod name
>   xyz
> Code:XY
> Color:Yellow [3413] (1 x 74 EUR) product name
>   xyz
> Code:XZ [22] (2 x 85 EUR) prod name zzz
> Code:XY
> Color:
>   Black

The main advantage is that every line is separated by `\n` and product ids are in square brackets.

Knowing that I've selected all MySQL entries in a `while` loop, how could I get all product codes (in this example: 32, 42, 66, ... ) for each order entry (preferabble in an array)?

Rather, how to get only value 32 from this string:

> [32] (1 x 22 EUR) prod name wxy
> Code:XY
> Color:LRC Red Cherry

Note: looking at first 2 lines, there is a `<br/>` tag between

> wxy

and

> Code

, but there is always a \n "before" every [id].

Comment: Your database needs a serious effort on normalization... This looks more like an hand-made bill than something done through a software.

Comment: I agree your suggestion, but firstly I have to update the database (currently, it stores like I've explained). It contains thousands of entries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restructure your data this is going to be a pain to deal with in the future. You could use a regex with `preg_match_all` for your current issue.

```
<?php
$string = '[32] (1 x 22 LEI) prod name wxy
Code:XY
Color:LRC Red Cherry [42] (1 x 33 LEI) prod name fgh
Code:XY
Color:pink [66] (1 x 44 LEI) prod name abc
Code:YU
Color:LPK Pink [60] (6 x 45 LEI) prd name xyz
Code:XY [1965] (1 x 32 LEI) prod name xyz
Code:XY
Color:Yellow [3413] (1 x 74 LEI) product name xyz
Code:XZ [22] (2 x 85 LEI) prod name zzz
Code:XY
Color: Black';
preg_match_all('~\[(\d+)\]~', $string, $ids);
print_r($ids[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
    [1] => 42
    [2] => 66
    [3] => 60
    [4] => 1965
    [5] => 3413
    [6] => 22
)
```

This regex pulls all numbers (`\d+`) inside `[]`. The tildes are just delimiters saying where the regex starts and ends. The delimiter could be anything but whatever is used will need to be escaped if used in the regex.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I were expecting for. I didn't quite understood preg_match syntax, even I had seen it more times. Now I have to normalize the DB and to insert the details every time an order is placed.

Comment: No problem. Also note that with this answer we aren't using the `0` index, we're using `1`. The zero index is everything that was found. The rest of the keys are each captured group. Since we are only capturing one value we use the `1` here.

Answer (score 0):

To get 32 you can use regex with matching groups

```
<?php
Preg_match_all('#(\[?<productId>[0-9]{1,}\])#', $string, $matches).
```

This should also work with a list of products.